# Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command

Tags: ios, selenium-webdriver, automation, xcuitest

I am new in `iOS automation` and using `Appium` command line for this. I have script ready to launch the app(Integration app) in real device and Whenever I run the script in `Eclipse`, I keep getting the following error when running the scripts:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
> ```
>
> Original error: Could not install app: 'Command 'ios-deploy --id
>   f31936d8edc3b8f880254efd02006273e81f5b --bundle
>   /Users/eeposit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntegrationApp.app'
>   exited with code 253' (WARNING: The server did not provide any
>   stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 9.97 seconds
>       Build info: version: '3.8.1', revision: '6e95a6684b', time: '2017-12-01T19:05:14.666Z'
>       System info: host: 'eeposits-Mac-mini-2.local', ip: '192.168.0.106', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version:
>   '10.13.2', java.version: '9.0.1'
>       Driver info: driver.version: IOSDriver
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
>   Method)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>         at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>         at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:488)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:214)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:166)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$new$0(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:53)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonWireProtocolResponse.lambda$getResponseFunction$2(JsonWireProtocolResponse.java:91)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.lambda$createSession$0(ProtocolHandshake.java:123)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195)
>         at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:958)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:127)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:502)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:488)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
>         at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:476)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:126)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:73)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:142)
>         at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:89)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:601)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:42)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>         at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:219)
>         at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:142)
>         at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:38)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:83)
>         at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:93)
>         at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.(IOSDriver.java:78)
>         at FirstiOS.iosautomate.main(iosautomate.java:43)

I have successfully installed the command `[ npm install -g ios-deploy ]` too but still the error is shown.

So, below are the capabilities that I have added.

```
capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APPIUM_VERSION, "1.7.2");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "iOS");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "9.3.3");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME, "iPhone 5s");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID, "f31936d8edc3b8f880254efd02006273e81f5b");
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.APP, "/Users/eeposit/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/IntegrationApp.app");
        capabilities.setCapability("bundleId", "com.facebook.IntegrationApp");
        capabilities.setCapability(IOSMobileCapabilityType.LAUNCH_TIMEOUT, 500000);
        capabilities.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.AUTOMATION_NAME, AutomationName.IOS_XCUI_TEST);
```

Please go through the image of the appium logs too that I have attached here: [Appium logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SryEw.png)

> [XCUITest] Error: Could not install app Command 'ios-deploy --id...exited with code 253

Any suggestions or help ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're attempting to install a simulator build onto a real device. You'll need to build for the proper architecture of the device that you want to test on, and then update your MobileCapabilityType.APP value to match. Something like:

"/Users/.../Xcode/DerivedData/WebDriverAgent-dikkwtrisltbeobjmfvpthwwekvs/Build/Products/**Debug-iphoneos**/IntegrationApp.app");

This error message is discussed at some length in Appium's issue tracker [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/7712).

Comment: Oh yeah that might be the issue. And for the error message, I will follow appium's issue tracker. Thanks @cbutton9

Comment: Thanks, @rshrestha! If this helped you out, I'd definitely appreciate an "upvote" or "accept" to help me build my site reputation.

Comment: Yeah, that helped me out after updating with real device build and updating MobileCapabilityType.APP path too. Thanks @cbutton9